# Search for files in all subfolders matching specific pattern in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a directory tree as shown below.
In words, the root directory contains multiple sub-directories, with arbitrary names. each of which may contain two folders: "OK" and "NotOK". These folders contain images classified as "happy" or "sad", which is reflected by their names.

```
root/
    dir0/
        OK/
            img_happy_001.png
            img_happy_002.png
            img_sad_001.png
            ...
        NotOK/
            img_happy_103.png
            img_happy_104.png
            img_sad_72.png
            ...
    dir1/
        OK/
            img_happy_501.png
            img_sad_233.png
            ...
        NotOK/
            img_happy_703.png
            img_happy_704.png
            img_sad_298.png
            ...
    ...
```

I could easily find all images classified as "happy" by doing

```
find . -name "*happy*.png"
```

However, I would like to **find all images classified as "happy" that are in an "OK"-directory**. How can I do this?

Comment: You can use path option, try `find . -path 'dir*/OK/*happy*'`

Comment: @geckos I'm not sure that will work because `path` seems to have a limited scope

Answer (score 2):

you could simply pipe the results from find into grep:

`find . -name "*happy*.png" | grep -v NotOK`

The `grep` command will filter the results from `find` that do not contain `NotOK`.

Alternatively you can look at `--whole-name` option in find.

I believe you would need something like:

`find . -name "*happy*.png" -wholename "\*/OK\*"`

Answer (score 0):

I acquired the desired result using

```
find . -type d -name "OK" -exec find {} -name "*happy*" \;
```

Comment: This way you have to run `find` twice while if you use the `-wholename` option you can do it with a single run